# JSONparse images from css

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, image

i'm trying to make an array, JSONparse it, and assign it to a css background image.

here's what i have: (javascript)

```
var imgs =  '{"num":[{"value": 1}, {"value": 2}, {"value": 3}, {"value": 4}, {"value": 5}, {"value": 6}, {"value": 7}, {"value": 8}, {"value": 9}]}';
console.log(imgs);
var img = JSON.parse(imgs);
```

image from css:

```
div#gamearea4x4 div.row1#ga4r12{
    background-image: url(../graphics/1.png);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
```

all i wanna do now is get the background image from the css and assign these values to the images (ex: 1.png has a value of 1, 2png has a value of 2, etc.)
also, i cannot specifically use the div tags because these images will be randomized (ex: #ga4r12 id can have 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc.)

How should i do it?

Comment: You also need separate divs to be assigned the background images?

Comment: Why create a string and then parse it? Why not create the object directly?

Comment: yes, there are a total of 16 different divs (#ga4r11, #ga4r12, etc) and each div can have any of the images from 1.png to 9.png (will be randomized)

Comment: i'm not exactly sure how to do it D':

Answer (score 0):

Randomly assign background to divs. You need to specify a container, or else all your divs will get assigned an image

```
var imgs =  '{"num":[{"value": 1}, {"value": 2}, {"value": 3}, {"value": 4}, {"value": 5}, {"value": 6}, {"value": 7}, {"value": 8}, {"value": 9}]}';
var img = JSON.parse(imgs);
$("div").each(function(){
  $(this).attr('style','background-image:url(../graphics/'+ img.num[Math.floor(Math.random()*img.num.length)].value + '.png)')
})
```

Also, you can just create an object like this

```
var imgs =
 {
  num: [{
    value: 1
  }, {
    value: 2
  }, {
    value: 3
  }, {
    value: 4
  }, {
    value: 5
  }, {
    value: 6
  }, {
    value: 7
  }, {
    value: 8
  }, {
    value: 9
  }]
}
```

Comment: how do i check the functionality

Comment: I do not understand your question. I have included jQuery in my solution. Maybe you also need jQuery